# Devise on Rails timeout on :token_authenticatable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

do you know how to configure a timeout on:token_authenticatable strategy on devise on Rails?

I set both :timeoutable and :token_authenticatable

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable,
          :token_authenticatable, :lockable
```

If I login with username and password, the timeout is correctly taken into account and I am asked to relogin again, while the token I set when I login it is not giving any timeout and it is always valid, until I do a proper logout (as I set a current_user.reset_authentication_token! in the destroy method).
Is there an easy way to set a token timeout not too intrusively (ie. modifying the devise code) or without hack (ie to have a cron job which is regularly checking last sign_in and reset the token if necessary)?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did similar thing with rake tasks:

```
namespace :app_name do
  desc "reset all auth_tokens"
  task :reset_auth => :environment do
    users = User.find(:all)
    users.each do |user|
      user.reset_authentication_token!
    end
  end
end
```

And then cron:

```
rake app_name:reset_auth
```

Comment: Look an approach feasible enough. Thanks for the code example, I will implement it as well in this way.